# Flip text in LCD screen

Tags: lcd

Im using <LiquidCrystal.h> arduino library,on a 2x16 LCD screen, with an accelerometer. I'd like to flip the the text when my x value exceeds N value. I get how to output text.
I tried straight up flipping the text, with an online converter, but the text that renders is garbage.
  `lcd.print("¡pןɹoʍ 'oןןǝɥ");  // Print a message to the LCD.`

[image]

Comment: what does this actually mean? ... `flip text`

Comment: @jsotola it means to rotate the letters. see example in the question. as Majkenko points out unicode chars wont do. but i have an idea.

Comment: I asked because it could also mean to reverse the background and foreground colors

Comment: @jsotola, ah I see.

Comment: can you link the datasheet of the LCD you have

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's not possible. The text is a simple ASCII character set that is encoded in ROM. It can't (other than a few user-defined characters) be changed. And being simple ASCII it doesn't support any UNICODE characters which are used for "upside down" text.

To do what you want you'd need a graphical LCD screen instead of a pure text one.

Comment: maybe I can make a bunch of byte arrays and write my own alphabet of upside down glyphs. Im dyslexic AF so it should be fun. I wonder how much it'll occupy in memory

Comment: @j0h You only have 8 user defined characters. Not enough for the whole alphabet. Maybe enough for a short word or two...

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Hitachi_HD44780_LCD_controller